# Nikon D3300 and MeiKe MK-MP1 microphone results in pulsating sound

Tags: dslr, microphone

DSLR: Nikon D3300

Microphone: MeiKe MK-MP1

When using the microphone connected to the DSLR I only get a pulsating sound like the one in this video

I tried to change the automatic sound sensitivity to manual (different levels) but to no avail.

Any idea what is the cause of this or what solutions I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I would try another microphone with the same camera, or plug the mic into a different camera, to try and work out where the fault is.

Does the mic need a battery?  That can sometimes generate faults like this, if the battery is low.

From the [specs](https://www.dpreview.com/products/nikon/slrs/nikon_d3300/specifications), it looks as though that camera only has a mono mic input. From [their webpage](http://www.mkgrip.com/goods/show-251.html), it looks as though the microphone is a stereo mic, with a [TRS jack](https://audiouniversityonline.com/ts-vs-trs-vs-trrs-audio-connectors/) (tip, ring, sleeve).  Sometimes you can get incompatibilities depending on how the mic and the device expect to receive input signals.

If you have any mains cables or data cables trailing nearby between the camera and the mic, try moving them out of the way, and see if the hum lessens. Unbalanced mic cables are more susceptible to interference than [balanced cabling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_line).